# Armazenar vários estados booleanos em somente uma variável bool

Tags: c, c++, memória, booleano

O tipo `bool` tanto em `C` como em `C++` consome no mínimo 1 byte de memória para ser armazenado, vi que isso se deve por que ele precisa ser endereçado ou algo assim. Logo, teria como nesse 1 byte armazenar mais de um estado booleano já que true/false precisaria somente de 1 bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, primeiro que em C não existe o tipo `bool`, e nem acho que seja uma boa prática, mas se uma variável possui 8 bits, então obviamente você pode armazenar mais do que dois estados diferentes nessa variável.

O que eu faço a seguir não é algo exclusivo de nenhuma linguagem, pode ser feito em C ou C++, aqui eu faço em JavaScript pois é possível simular no site.

Utilizando um pouco de lógica e operadores binários, você pode comparar os valores dos bits para verificar se ele é `1` (`true`) ou `0` (`false`).

```js
var bool = 0b00000000 // false false false false false false false false
bool |= 0b00000101 // atribuo "true" para o primeiro e terceiro bit

console.log('primeiro bit é: ', (bool & 0b00000001) > 0) // true
console.log('segundo bit é: ', (bool & 0b00000010) > 0) // false
console.log('terceiro bit é: ', (bool & 0b00000100) > 0) // true
console.log('-----------------')

bool &= 0b11111110 // atribuo "false" para o primeiro bit

console.log('primeiro bit é: ', (bool & 0b00000001) > 0) // false
console.log('segundo bit é: ', (bool & 0b00000010) > 0) // false
console.log('terceiro bit é: ', (bool & 0b00000100) > 0) // true
console.log('-----------------')
```

Lembrando:

- 0 & 0 => 0
- 0 & 1 => 0
- 1 & 0 => 0
- 1 & 1 => 1
- 0 | 0 => 0
- 0 | 1 => 1
- 1 | 0 => 1
- 1 | 1 => 1

O que faço aqui é comparar todos os 8 bits com outros 8 bits. Se comparo o byte `0b00000001` com `bool`, e o primeiro bit de `bool` também é `1`, então o resultado será `0b00000001`, ou seja, maior que `0` (`0b00000000`), portanto o primeiro bit de `bool` é `true`.